# Typescript build object from type definition

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I want to create a React hook for retrieving url search params and return a correctly typed object, calling it like this:

```
const { id, slug } = useTypedSearchParams<{ id: number; slug: string }>();
```

This would return `id` typed as `number` and `slug` typed as `string`.

I have tried various implementations with no success, the main problem being building an object from a type definition and conditionally calling `parseInt` for `number` fields.

Comment: You can't build an object from a type definition dynamically, because types don't exist during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a library like Zod to handle this problem elegantly.
This version throws an exception in case of validation errors.

```ts
import { z } from 'zod';

function useTypedSearchParams<T extends z.Schema>(schema: T): z.infer<T> {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  return schema.parse(Object.fromEntries(searchParams));
}

function Home() {
  const mySearchParamsSchema = z.object({
    someText: z.coerce.string(),
    someNumber: z.coerce.number(),
    someBool: z.coerce.boolean().optional(),
  });
  try {
  const searchParams = useTypedSearchParams(mySearchParamsSchema);
  console.log('Search Params', searchParams);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return <p></p>
}
```

The type of search params is infeerred as follows:

```ts
const searchParams: {
    someText: string;
    someNumber: number;
    someBool?: boolean | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the closest we can get to this!

Comment: How would you modify it so that the hook call doesn't pass a `z.object` as argument, but rather create the schema inside the hook method?

Comment: I did it this way:

```
function useTypedSearchParams<T extends z.ZodRawShape>(schemaDefinition: T) {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const schema = z.object(schemaDefinition);

  return schema.parse(Object.fromEntries(searchParams));
}
```

This way you can call it like this:
```
const { id } = useTypedSearchParams({
    id: z.number(),
  });
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get somewhat the result that you want using this setup:

```js
type Converter<T> = (value: string | null) => T;

const stringConverter: Converter<string> = (value: string | null) => value as string;
const numberConverter: Converter<number> = (value: string | null) => Number(value);
const booleanConverter: Converter<boolean> = (value: string | null) => !!value && (/true/i).test(value);

function useTypedSearchParams<T>(
    converters: Record<string, Converter<any>>
) {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    const extracted: Record<string, unknown> = {};

    for (const key of Object.keys(converters)) {
        const value = searchParams.get(key);
        extracted[key] = converters[key](value);
    }

    return extracted;
}

const result = useTypedSearchParams({
    id: stringConverter,
    isNewUser: booleanConverter,
    pageNumber: numberConverter
});

console.log(result.id);
console.log(result.isNewUser);
console.log(result.pageNumber);
```

You will have to create a `converter` for every type that you want to extract from the search parameters. An issue that I was not able to solve currently is that the type of the values in `result` is still unknown, but you know that you converted them correctly so you can safely cast them.

[Working example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&id=test-id&isNewUser=true&pageNumber=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwG4QE7DQHgCoD4oC8UAFEgIYA2ArhAFxQDOwqAlggOZQA%20UCVFFAJSF82ANwAoCQGNETRszbt4yNBlT0VKdFiasO%20IqUo16epd178hIqOWrQyDBfvaTZCeXwC2AIzRaamiaiNrqmD7%20qIYk9qYuFjx8AsIE%20AByVH5oxg6C7nLAUL5wcBQQZAiBOhqwoUGomCVlFQgxufHmHJbJNmlQAIQDcdAAZKMkAPTMNJMsggB0GEwdEPlSAGZUCNLALIhQVAwQ2OAQACYAyhWo0gAWAApkqGTeDDi4xBJQP1AeYWgGPQAEoQWSoc6YLrsAA0dVUNUwlRAuFwEmEAG9vr8PPJjs97k8Xm9CLwIAB3KAAVWBABlrgTHs9XgxiOS2Oc4OSFhQ4NIyHtEAt8bc7utsT9cUUIAAPZhkXYXEFguAQqGKDhw7YAawQXLapIxAF9JBKoBtVSQpVBtRAQFA4BsoAB5XwAKzBwAWtpArP%20DQYgkxZt%20f0KdhM0CIIsJzLeC3YEGAxB961Dodl8sV5wA2j6ALqk-01Bh5u351Zp35GqSh1BJqioBBQTMvbOSGsycP1hj8IpEI4nM5XG6x4msrGhljnMwa5T1Gows0sBjpClU461ZrlSrVdRL0NgMiJzLZWqRAIL9QSI3i3EtHlwdjEHt9hbT9b38qP5%20vihelc13JDc0E-OQH15X8IF7f8FiPE8siifIgA).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's too bad that the type result is `unknown` because I liked the idea of not using an external library to achieve this

Comment: I played with this answer to improve types a little: https://tsplay.dev/WGGa2W